# is there any failsafe for android developer mode to prevent malicious attack?

Tags: android, android-security

well, is there any failsafe for preventing attacker can't enabled remotely either developer mode or ADB?
screen overlay touch prevention,

e.g. a prevent enabling developer menu on setting by disabling tap build number in special situation

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing special about activating developer mode. Attackers cannot fake touch events, outside of having convinced the user to make their malware an `AccessibilityService`, or perhaps through some unpatched security bugs on the device.

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is and it was introduced in the 4.2.2 update. Even is somehow developer mode was enabled, and you accidentally plugged in your phone to an unknown USB port, if the key provided by the host is unrecognized, you have the opportunity to sign it and allow it, or ignore it. If ignored, host device is unable to access your phone via ADB. Here is an in-depth article about this: https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html